# Quad Copter flight module can replace with smart phone?

Tags: arduino, quadcopter

I want to replace the flight module with smart phone because it has all sensors that are required, like gyroscope, magnetometer, etc. Is that possible?

I am using an Google Nexus 4 Android (OS model 5.1). I will control using another mobile, I am able write an app, with an Arduino acting as a bridge between smartphone and copter. I am using flight controller [OpenPilot CC3D CopterControl](https://www.openpilot.org/product/coptercontrol/).

Comment: Welcome to *robotics*.  Can you elaborate on this question?  We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it is a good idea to include details of what what you would like to achieve, what you have tried, what you expected to see and what you actually saw. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be a lot more specific in your question so you can get a meaningful answer:

- What smart phone are you connecting? Make, model, OS
- What flight module are you replacing?
- How will you be controlling the smart phone?
- Are you able to write an app for the smart phone?
- What will happen when the smart phone looses its signal?
- How will you connect the phone to the copter?
- Why have you tagged this with Arduino?

If you can provide more info then I can provide a more specific answer than: Maybe.

Comment: i am using Google Nexus 4 Android (OS model 5.1)

Comment: i am using Google Nexus 4 Android (OS model 5.1) i will control using another mobile,i am able write an app,arduino act as bridge b/w smartphone and copter.using flight controller CC3D  open pilot CopterControl.

Comment: i am trying this as my university project. i advance i will very very thank full to you Matt

Answer (score 3):

A project like this was already thought and working.

It was proposed from Vijay Kumar, one of the gurus of quarotor helicopers (that is the name he thinks it is the most appropriate for these objects).

I hope you will find the following link interesting:

[Vijay Kumar: a smartphone as brain for a quadrotor](http://spectrum.ieee.org/automaton/robotics/aerial-robots/a-smartphone-is-the-brain-for-this-autonomous-quadcopter)

[This is the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtTiPnNUKj8)